# call java web service from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-services

I would like to call my webservice methods from pure java script code. and that code should work on mozilla browser.

This is my webservice code:

```
package com.example.core;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class Area {

@WebMethod
public double square(@WebParam(name="side") double side)
{
return side * side;
}

@WebMethod
public double rectangle(@WebParam(name="length") double length,@WebParam(name="breadth") double breadth)
{
 return length * breadth;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Area area = new Area();
String url = "http://localhost:8090/area"; // end point of webservice.
 System.out.println(url+"?wsdl");
 Endpoint.publish(url, area);  // publishing the webservice
}
}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<meta content="text/xml;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script language="javascript">

function call()
{
var side = sideid.value;
var side1 = sideid1.value;
var req = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://core.codon.com/\"><soapenv:Body><web:rectangle><length>" + side+ "</length><breadth>" + side1+ "</breadth></web:rectangle></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
 //var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 //var reqXML = xmlDoc.loadXML(req);
 var xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
 xmlDoc.async=false;
 xmlDoc.onload = req; 
 //var reqXML = xmlDoc.load(req);
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
 {
  var response = xmlhttp.responseXML;

  alert(response.selectSingleNode(".//return").text);
   alert("======"+response);
  }
}
 var soapaction = "http://core.example.com/rectangle";
 xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8090/area?wsdl",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapaction);
 xmlhttp.send(req);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 Side Length: <input type="text" id="sideid"></input>
 Length: <input type="text" id="sideid1"></input>
 <button onclick="call();">area of square</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

with the above code am getting response as null. The same code working on IE but not in mozilla...

my webservice side am getting the following error

```
 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler handleExchange
 WARNING: Cannot handle HTTP method: OPTIONS
```

Please Help me out..Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a js framework like jquery. That will take care of most cross browser issues.

Comment: What is the xmlhttp.status? Do you see any errors?

Comment: am getting xmlhttp.status as 0

Comment: Chnage ur check to  `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)`

Comment: if i write if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) ..control not coming in to the if block..because am getting status code 0

Answer (score 1):

I would take SOAP UI, generate web service client, generate example requests, so I don't need to create  SOAP envelopes from scratch. Then I would use jQuery to generate AJAX requests with the help of generated SOAP envelopes.

Another approach would be to make use of http://cxf.apache.org/docs/javascript-clients.html - you will have complete JavaScript generated that way.

Comment: can you give me clear steps...because am newbie to webservices...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are running webservice as stand alone app on port say 'x' and the client might be on another port say 'y'
When you do a post call through y onto x the method will always be changed to options automatically. Internet standards wont allow 'posting' between different servers, I guess.
You will have to find another workaround.